# OpenGraph share posts only visible to me

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-opengraph

In swift 4 I am sharing a post to my Facebook feed using the Open Graph API. This successfully posts to my feed, but other users in my friends list can't see the share post, only I can - even though the post is set to public.

Is there anything else I need to do for other users to see the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it still in sandbox mode? You need to set the Facebook app live, then other users will be able to see the share.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Cheers!